# python for loop processed in strict order

Tags: python, loops, sorting, for-loop

I am using a python for loop to process json data, but I need to enforce certain data is processed first. What I want to happen is within my list, items  where each_ADSL["VRF"] = 17 are processed before any others.

My json data i am interpreting looks something like this:

```
  "ADSL": [
{
  "CE_HOSTNAME": "TESTCE-DCNCE-01",
  "VRF": "19",
},
{
  "CE_HOSTNAME": "TESTCE-DCNCE-01",
  "VRF": "17",
}
]
```

I am interpreting this, then processing the data:

```
for each_ADSL in order["ADSL"]:
    do something
```

This needs to take into account numbers lower than 17 (so a simple sort won't work.) Can i turn order["ADSL"] into a list and sort it by criteria somehow?

Comment: Why not append the elements containing the value 17 into a new list. Process that and then come back to process the old list

Comment: Your logic knows no bounds.

Comment: What do you mean by "Can i turn order["ADSL"] into a list"? Isn't that already a list

Comment: Yes, it is already a list, but it isn't specifcally defined i.e mylist = order["ADSL"] . I thought i could manipluate mylist in ways i could not referencing order["ADSL"].

Comment: So we can append the elements into new lists right?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, append stuff which =17 to the list, then append anything which != 17 afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this

```
myjson = {
    "ADSL": [
        {
            "CE_HOSTNAME": "TESTCE-DCNCE-01",
            "VRF": "19",
        },
        {
            "CE_HOSTNAME": "TESTCE-DCNCE-01",
            "VRF": "17",
        }
    ]
}


mylist = myjson["ADSL"]

list17 = []

for item in mylist:
    if item["VRF"] == "17":
        list17.append(item)

for item in list17:
    do_first_action()

for item in mylist:
    if item["VRF"] != "17":
        do_second_action()
```

Comment: Why even create a second list? Instead of adding data to a new list and then later loop over that list you can just call `do_first_action()` the first time you run through the list if `item["VRF"]` is `"17"`.

Comment: Yes that is obviously doable. Just wanted to make it more specific so that the list17 can be used for all the operations involving those elements